# google search console tells me that I have a crawling error

Tags: wordpress, search, console

I have a problem with Wordpress and the Search Console. The Search Console from Google tells me that I have a crawling error on the smartphone.

The error details are:

> Googlebot could access your site, but certain URLs are blocked for Googlebot Mobile for smartphones in your *robots.txt*. These URLs are not included in the "Blocked URLs" report and may have been blocked unintentionally.

I have already seen the `customize.php`, but I have no idea what I should change or how I can solve the problem.

Any help would be appreciated! Additionally, are there detailed instructions anywhere for beginners? Many thanks in advance!!

Best regards, Sandra [2 images here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxaFd.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that WordPress is not configured to tell search bots to not index your site? Login to your admin, then navigate to **Settings -> Reading** and make sure '*Discourage search engines from indexing this site*' is not ticked.

[Here is a screenshot to help you find it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ty3jX.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your quick reply. I have been convinced for safety, but the function is switched off for me.